# Designing a good database

Tags: database, database-design

I have the following tree:

`courses`, that have many `groups`, each having multiple `students`.
So the drilled-down tree looks like this: courses -> groups -> students.

I think there are two ways to represent this:

1) `students` table that has `group_id` FK to `groups`; `groups` table that has `course_id` FK or:

2) first option plus `students` table having both `group_id` and `course_id` FKs so that I can have more freedom to fetch data without having to `JOIN` the "parent" table everytime.

One good example is to get all students that are part of a course (whatever the group). In this case, going with only the first option forces me to `JOIN` the `groups` table, which is not needed in that scope. So i tend to always choose the second option, even if the "main" table gets a few more columns of FKs.

How do you approach this?

The example gets more complicated if you add a couple more tables at the top of the `courses` table, like `teachers` (that teach `courses`) and `schools` (that has `teachers`). If you need to see all the students in a school, you need to join the groups, courses, teachers and schools.

Thank you!

LE: I am excluding many to many relationships from this example, those are treated differently.

LLE: And yes, if it sounds like convenience (aka performance)... it might be true :)

Comment: Option 1 is the better one. Even if you have to use the `group` table for getting the `students` of a `course`, the database does not contain redundant information. There is not problem for the DBMS as well, the optimizers are good in such cases, you will not get any delayed results. Option 2 would be an option if you have `students` in a `course` which are not in any `group`. But if the condition holds that each `student` is in a `group` you should use option 1. Transitivity works fine here.

Comment: Maybe you could use a view to avoid joining all the time.

Comment: @Drudge: without knowing the database, nor the full model, nor the data size, you cannot make the claim "you will not get any delayed results".  Denormalizing a data model is exactly what you do to help improve the read speed in cases like this. What you describe is more of a "logical" model and you typically do not include any redundancy on that level ... you add it at the final level on the physical model ... as needed.  It's an option, and a valid one ... whether or not he NEEDS to do it is another discussion entirely ;)

Comment: @Ditto that is right. It's a comment instead of an answer because it's my personal opinion. I always try to archive normalized databases. What happens when the `student` is in more than one `group` (which means he is in more than one `course`)? This will not work well. Edit: I meant that what jpw wrote seconds ago. It's not guranteed having a one-to-one relationship between a `student` and a `course`.

Comment: @jpw: No, a student only belongs to one group and one course. It is an example just to see how do you approach this kind of problem, when you need the top parent of a "5 level-deep" table.

Comment: @Drudge: I actually thought of the "what if student had more than 1 course", however, aside from Marius's confirmation: the model/relationship he showed in the original question restricts a student to only 1 course (which sounds kind of odd in it's own right, but oh well ;) )

Comment: @Ditto: Yes, it's just an example, not a real-world scenario. But it might apply in some many cases :)

Comment: @Marius: I thought so, which is why I wasn't overly concerned about the real world course <-> student relationship ;)  Hope you got your answer ! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I try to keep a database as normalized as possible for clarity in the data model.  So I would say if every student is going to be linked to the course through a group (no possibility of a student not in a group), than there should not be a relationship directly between students and courses.  Don't sacrifice the clarity of your data model for having to write less SQL.

Also, you probably realize this, but you'll need linking tables for any many-to-many relationships.  I'm not sure what kind of groups you're talking about, but if they can exist over multiple courses you'll need a Course --> CourseGroup (FK CourseID, FK GroupID) --> Group structure, and if students can belong to multiple groups you'll need Group --> GroupMembership (FK GroupID, FK StudentID)--> Student.

Comment: No many to many relationships in this case. I know that that approach is different, I was only curious about one to one link between the tables and how do you query the top table from the bottom table.

Comment: Ok that makes sense.  My first paragraph applies then: joining one data type to others through associated types is what relational databases are all about, and it becomes more and more obvious the more complicated the data model.  Think Country -> State -> County -> City -> District -> etc...  If you linked all of those back to Country than you would have a wildly complex data model.

Answer (score 2):

The addition of the `course_id` into the `students` table would be considered "denormalization" and is perfectly acceptable for exactly the reason you are trying to solve : "performance".

[Denormalization Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization)

> In computing, denormalization is the process of attempting to optimize the read performance of a database by adding redundant data or by grouping data

So yeah, your second option is doing just this ... attempting to improve performance by adding redundant data.